# Toggle hidden row with button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where each visible row has a row beneath it whose visibility can be toggled by pressing a button. A live demo of this can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cz6vLq8j/).

I'm really new to using jQuery and the problem I'm encountering is probably a simple fix to be honest. First of all, I want the togglable rows to be hidden by default and only shown when the button is clicked (now they show when the page is loaded). How can I do this?

To hide the rows I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $(".trhideclass1").toggle();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $(".trhideclass2").toggle();
    });
});
```

I don't want to have to create a function for every button separately, so what is a better way to do this? My idea was to give a `<button>` and `<tr>` the same `id` and somehow make the button only toggle stuff with the same `id`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the buttons (like `btn-toggle`) and then traverse the DOM for getting the target element:

```
$(".btn-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggle();
});
```

The values passed to the `.closest` and `.next` methods can be any valid selector. For understanding how these methods work you can refer to the jQuery documentations.

https://jsfiddle.net/mc1dkq6a/

Answer (score 0):

You can set default hide in css

```
  .trhideclass1,.trhideclass2{
      display : none;
    }
```

For more easy to handle you should change your button id only as `number`

HTML

```
<button id="1" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
<button id="2" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        current = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.trhideclass'+current).toggle();
    });
});
```